# Do ASMX or WCF Proxy clients use IO completion ports?

Tags: wcf, multithreading, io, asmx

I'm in the middle of performance testing a critical section of my project, when I notice a whole lot of extra threads being used to to perform WaitOrTimerCallback operations.

[alt text http://lh4.ggpht.com/_p7-jVU64mGg/SZuWgUvTD7I/AAAAAAAAAEk/PUFrXrYvZh0/threads_thumb%5B1%5D.jpg?imgmax=800](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_p7-jVU64mGg/SZuWgUvTD7I/AAAAAAAAAEk/PUFrXrYvZh0/threads_thumb%5B1%5D.jpg?imgmax=800)

On closer inspection I can see that these are being spawned by my ASMX client proxy class for operations on a remote server.

I was under the impression that these were using IO completion ports like all of my other asynchronous IO Calls.

Is it possible to get a ASMX or WCF proxy client to use IO Completion ports? If not - really what is the point?

[UPDATE]
The project was using ASMX proxy client(s).  It appears that they are using the normal thread pool inorder to register a WaitOrTimerCallback.  I'm now working with WCF Proxy clients.  These are not spawning extra threads so i can only assume they are using the desired IO completion ports.

The ASMX Proxy class was created using Visual Studio 2008.  I had added the following line to the the project file: "WebReference_EnableLegacyEventingModel>true" As the current flavour of ASMX clients do not have Asynchronous enabled by default.

Comment: The Threads Called "Default Dispatcher" should be the only threads "really active"

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for ASMX, but WCF definitely does (and like you I'd be surprised if ASMX doesn't).  Can you get the call stacks to ensure that they really are blocked on network calls (and not some other user code)?